# JPG PNG pics converted into PS layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a basic knowledge of layers.

How do I convert pictures (JPG, PNG, GIF) (which can be opened into a new PhotoShop window via Windows Explorer or any other file manager) to PhotoShop layers?

I want to merge these pictures with layers I've created myself in PhotoShop.  Is it possible to add layers in this manner?

Comment: @Hennes, in this context, PS = PhotoShop.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SuperUser! When you say PS, I'm assuming you're talking about the application Photoshop, not the file format PostScript. The command I think you're looking for is the Place command, found in the file menu. It will let you add an image to an existing Photoshop document.

If you want the image to become its own layer, then you should create a new blank layer and make sure it is selected prior to using the place command.

Comment: Yes it's Photoshop! But it'll say that when the image/pic is placed onto PS via the Place command then i can make a real layer out of it ? And how do i do this ? This wehat i want to know :-)

Comment: I've added additional information to my answer.

Comment: Super! Thanks for the information. Sometimes a little confusing about layers mechanisms.

Comment: If my answer solves your problem, I'd appreciate it if you accepted it by clicking the grey check on the left. This makes it easier to determine which questions should be kept so other users can benefit and which ones should be deleted.

Comment: Of course they’re referring to PhotoShop, it’s right there in the tag. And I think you’re over-complicating it. They already have a basic knowledge of layers, they just want to merge them.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a few ways to add an image to a layer. In increasing order of difficulty/work:

- Just [drag them into the document](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS52326498-2970-4129-BFF6-84CFE281771D.html#WS8B37F6C0-7854-4904-934E-EC109F3A3490a); PhotoShop will automatically creates [Smart Object Layers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS41A5B796-6846-4e95-8459-95243441E126.html) for them.
- Use the [*Place* command](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-78f2a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-78f0a) (*File ⇨ Place*) to open the file as a Smart Object Layer.
- Create layers manually, open the images separately, then copy-paste them into the layers.

You can [convert](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS41A5B796-6846-4e95-8459-95243441E126.html#WSE8BD6DD9-47E4-40a4-B363-033CD6CD8D33a) a Smart Object Layer to a regular layer by selecting it, then using *Layer ⇨ Rasterize ⇨ Smart Object*.

Once you are done with the layers, use the *Flatten* command (*Layers ⇨ Flatten Image*) to merge them.